# If statement applied to a math algorithm.elasticity and velocity

Tags: calculus

So my problem, is basically I am trying to work out the distance something is as time t progresses.

The algorithm I am using is the elastic acceleration applied to an initial velocity, however I can only think of applying the elastic acceleration one way and not sure how to make it go positive when the distance is negative, and then negative when the distance is negative,

so that you can see the elastic bounce effect, in a plotted equation.

I am using acceleration = -Kd^2
(negative elasticity)

then solving for differential of the velocity to get distance and then substituting it in.

However how do i make the acceleration change based on the distance factor. greater than 0 or less than 0.

Am I going about this the right way?

Comment: How about: Instead of
$$
a = -kd^2
$$
try
$$
a = -sgn{(d)} Kd^2
$$
where $sgn{(d)}$ is the sign of $d$ (-1 for negative and +1 for positive)

Comment: Also, it seems weird that distance would be negative. What is it that you're modelling? Think about the case physically. What happens if the distance is -1 as compared to +1 ?

Comment: @MattiP. ill try that thanks. The behaviour is similar to a rubber band, I am trying to have the elastic bounce backwards and forwards from the middle point (0), based on the initial velocity. So +1 would be 1 unit infront of the center, and -1 would be 1 unit behind the center. Does that make sense ? Am I going about this the right way ? haha

Comment: just like vertical motion